# TimePicker Razor ASP.NET-MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, timepicker

I'm trying to create a TimePicker with Razor and JQueryUI in my bootstrap web. I created a DatePicker, and I know that I could create a DateTimePicker with JQuery, but I don't want to select the date and the time together, I want to select it with two different TextBox.

So I saw many tutorials, but all of them create a DateTimePicker, and when I tried to create a TimePicker with the same format, that didn't worked for me.

This is my code:

JavaScript:

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            showOptions: { speed: 'fast' },
            changeMonth: false,
            changeYear: false,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            gotoCurrent: true
        });
        $('#timepicker').timepicker();
    });  
</script>
```

Razor and Html:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.TextBox("date", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), new { @id = "datepicker", @readonly = "readonly", @style = "width:250px;" })
        <br />
        @Html.TextBox("time","-- Select Time --", new { @id = "timepicker", @readonly = "readonly", @style = "width:250px;" })
    }
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: TypeError: $(...).timepicker is not a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery-UI addon is required for timepicker control.

check here : https://jsfiddle.net/dmc55erf/8/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.1/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.1/jquery.timepicker.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                showOptions: { speed: 'fast' },
                changeMonth: false,
                changeYear: false,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                gotoCurrent: true
            });
            $('#timepicker').timepicker();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: still not working, I have this error now "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'", I have your code and at the Html the same code, what could it be?

Comment: @Estel_Rebel Please check now .Made some changes.